# How to make image fit in div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple card, where image should cover/fit the full width of the container div.
My desired style would be something similar like in the image below.
[image]

I tried to apply `object-fit:cover` with `100% width` but didn't help.

Here is how it looks like now

[image]

Here is related code and [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-morse-ypypmn?file=/src/Card.module.css)
html/jsx

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Card.module.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.cardWrapper}>
      <img
        src="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAyNFg1NzY=/z/qWYAAOSwm1Vcc6F4/$_72.JPG"
        alt="description"
      />
      <h3 style={{ fontSize: "15px" }}>title</h3>
      <div className={styles.description}>description</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and css

```
.cardWrapper {
  width: 165px;
  height: 192px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.description {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #808080;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.cardWrapper img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `width: auto` and `height: auto` from your `.cardWrapper img`:

```css
.cardWrapper {
  width: 165px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.description {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #808080;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.cardWrapper img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardWrapper">
  <img
    src="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAyNFg1NzY=/z/qWYAAOSwm1Vcc6F4/$_72.JPG"
    alt="description"
  />
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="description">description</div>
</div>
```

You were overwriting your already working 100% rules, so just leave them in, and remove anything else. You dont need the object-fit either.

As stated by @louielyl in the comments:
remove the absolute height on the `.cardWrapper` as well, otherwise the description has no room left in the wrapper and falls out.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried in sandbox, but it puts the description outside of the box.

Comment: it went outside the box because you set an absolute height to the box, you might want to remove it as well.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your `width:100%` and `height:100%` didn't work is because your latter css `width: auto;` `height: auto;` overwrite them.

Try this and you will see your image grows as expected:

```css
.cardWrapper img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

It happens because it is CSS's behavior to override with the latter styling that has the same property, for details, you could take a look at [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).